# Blocking Administrator from accessing certain folders - Windows Server 2008 std

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

We've a server 2008 Std installed on our network.

I want to setup 2 folders, that will be shared only with two relevant users.  I've changed the Security to just those users, however when I double click on them while logged in as Administrator, all I have to do is click "continue" and the administrator gets added to the permissions.

Is it possible to block these from being viewed by the administrators?  I seem to remember that on older systems you could do this.  If the administrator NEEDED access, they then had to take ownership etc.  This would still be acceptable for me.

Thanks,

Enda.

Answer (score 4):

You can't block an administrator from anything. If you need to restrict access, take away their membership in the Administrators group. As you've mentioned, they can just take ownership.

If you look closely as what the UAC prompt is asking you for permission to do, it's likely taking ownership of the folder and adding an explicit ACE for the current user, just in one click instead of 10.